# ASP.NET Core can't append cookies

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to append a cookie on one of my controllers, when it has been called. But the cookie ends up in a property called "NonValidated" and isn't set on the client. I don't use any authentication or authorization.
This is what my controller looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
        {
            string requestBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            var pass = _configuration.GetSection("Password").Value;

            if (requestBody == pass)
            {
                    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("logged-in", "true", new CookieOptions
                {
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
                    IsEssential = true
                });

                return Ok("Login successful");
            }
            return Unauthorized("Incorrect Password");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I call the api from the same application from a razor page where I then redirect based on what the cookie says. This is the method where I call the api:

```
private async Task<bool> Login(string password)
{
    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
    var content = new StringContent(password, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:7236/api/login", content);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I've tried multiple things but can't seem to make it work. When I call the api using postman, the cookie is set correctly in the response. Anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: Are your API and razor pages on the same port?

Comment: @corey-sutton Yes, they are currently on the same port!

Comment: not sure how it's going to set a cookie when it's called from another server... you've sort of gobbled up the response/header there in that second method (controller calling another controller?)

Comment: Could you please include the details of `_configuration.GetSection` how have you configured there, In addition, while writing cookie, have you checked if that has been generated in broweser?

Comment: @md-farid-uddin-kiron That's for getting a string from a JSON file. I've debugged it, and the value is correct and the if statement is running like it should. Yes, I have checked the browser cookies, and no cookie is being created.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried multiple things but can't seem to make it work. When I call
> the api using postman, the cookie is set correctly in the response.
> Anyone know what the issue could be?

Well, based on your shared code snippet and description it seems that your cookie configuration may not correct which has not been shared. You are setting directly on  `HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append` not sure, if you have registered the `AddHttpContextAccessor` in your program.cs file in order to access httpContex.

I have tried in following way and its working as expected:

Interface:

```
public interface IAppManager
    {
        public string ReadCookie(string key);
        public void WriteCookie(string key, string value, int? daysToPersist = null);
        public void DeleteCookie(string key);
    }
```

Implementation:

```
public class AppManager : IAppManager
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public AppManager(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public string ReadCookie(string key)
        {
          
            var data = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[key];

            return data;
        }

        public void WriteCookie(string key, string value, int? daysToPersist = null)
        {
            
            var options = new CookieOptions
            {
             
                Secure = true,
                IsEssential = true,
                HttpOnly = false
            };


            if (daysToPersist > 0)
                options.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays((double)daysToPersist);
            else
                options.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds((double)60);

            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(key, value, options);

        }

        public void DeleteCookie(string key)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(key);
        }

    }
```

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddScoped<IAppManager, AppManager>();


builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();


...
```

Controller:

```
public class CookieManagerController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAppManager _cookieManager;

        public CookieManagerController(IAppManager appManager)
        {
            _cookieManager = appManager;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            _cookieManager.WriteCookie("CookieKey", "Kiron Cookie Test", 30);
            ViewBag.CookieName = _cookieManager.ReadCookie("CookieKey");
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**Note:** For web API you should set response header in session and then need to extract the value from session. You can [refer to this document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies)

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to the official document for details configuration.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-6.0#api-usage-with-samesite)